# Error implementing UIWebView to load local html

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

am trying to add a UIWebView to my current UIScrollView. The UIWebView is supposed to access a local html file 'index.html'. I got an error at runtime:

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'
```

This is my code:

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:scrollViewFrame];
    NSString *indexPath = [NSBundle pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"Addition"];
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:indexPath]]];
```

I do have 'Addition' folder (not group; imported from 'Add' in my project).

Thanx in advance...

Comment: Is addition going over the wire as a "Copy Bundle Resource"?

Comment: When i add the folder i choose
1)Copy items into destination group's folder
2)Create folder references for any added folder
3)Add to target
Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check `indexPath` with a breakpoint or `NSLog`? It looks like your file is not there (perhaps a typo?)-

EDIT

OK, I just tested this successfully. Try this:

1. Delete all the web files from your project.
2. Copy the web directory into the right place in your project folder.
3. Drag from Finder to Xcode, do not copy, Create folder references

One more caveat: Maybe there is a difference in **capitalized resource names** between the simulator and the device. Try using lowercase throughout.

Also, you should perhaps correct your command pulling the resource from the bundle. Instead of

```
[NSBundle pathForResource...
```

it should be

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource...
```

Comment: I did it with breakpoint. How do i do it with nslog? Negative.. Its not a typo :(

Comment: Edited my answer with my test setup.

Comment: Still couldn't work. NSLog still returns null.
I redeleted the folder and dragged in just the index.html. Changed the directory to NULL since i'm not using any folders. Still doesn't work. 
My project is a TabBar app with ARC. Could that affect anything?

Comment: This is very frustrating... lol... i'm going crazy over something rather simple...